# Trying to understand the last line of code

Tags: javascript

I have this snippet of code:

```
(function(){
    var d = {
        sayHello: function(a){
            document.writeln("Hello "+a)
        }
    }
    this.d = d;
})();
```

I know that this is an IIFE, but the last line confuses me. Is it for the object `d` to get outside of the scope? It's used like an API that can be accessed, right?

`this.d = d` means that `d` is now a variable on the scope, ready to use?

Is there any other way to accomplish that?

Comment: is this all of your code?

Comment: yes im starting to write an api, first wanna understand how to do it.

Comment: if `this` points to `window` (which is the case) then yes, your variable is now globally available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the IIFE is invoked directly with `()` there is no "context", so `this` will default (in non-ES5-strictmode) to `window`.

Hence the line is equivalent to:

```
window.d = d;
```

and yes, therefore exposing `d` into the global namespace.

You shouldn't use this method because it's not compatible with ES5 `"use strict"` which sets `this = null` in the absence of an explicit context.  I would recommend something like this, instead:

```
var MYNAMESPACE = MYNAMESPACE || {};
MYNAMESPACE.SUBPACKAGE = (function() {
    ...
    return d;
})();
```

Comment: And what should i use? I mean to encapsulate the code and then expose the object to use as an API. thanks